# How to write procedure to get all the data of table of tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a master table which contains the table names and columns corresponding to that table.

I want to write a procedure which iterates through all the records of tables and gets all the data and returns it as a single result set.

Comment: Which one is it? Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: Simple answer is `Dynamic Query`. Also the datatypes of all the columns should be same.

Comment: For Oracle, you can use `Type ` which is similar to your table structure and mention it in `out` condition

Comment: please post some sample data and expected result to avoid modifications later and also for better answers

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is for SQL SERVER but a solution in oracle is also welcomed

Comment: It's impossible to write a single answer for both DBMS they are just way too different (_especially_ when it comes to returning result sets from stored procedures).

Comment: can we return result of multiple selects in single result set

Comment: Sounds like a horribly bad idea .... how do you want to return a **single** result set, if all those tables have different structure?? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Dynamic Query`

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)=''

SET @sql = (SELECT @sql + 'select ' + column_name + ' from '
                   + table_name + ' union all '
            FROM   master_table
            FOR xml path(''))

SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql, Len(@sql) - 9) 
EXEC (@sql)
```

**Note :** The datatype of all the columns should be same. If it is not the case then you may have to do explicit conversion to `varchar`

```
SET @sql = (SELECT @sql + 'select cast(' + column_name + ' as varchar(4000)) from '
                        + table_name
                   + ' union all '
            FROM   Master_table
            FOR xml path(''))
```

Comment: yeah... and of course the number of columns should be same :)

Comment: but i have different no of columns for different tables

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all tables listed in your Master table is having same columns with same order and data types. Then it will be as follows:

```
create table ##a
(
    Value int
)

create table ##b
(
    Value int
)

create table ##c
(
    Value int
)

declare @all table
(
    Value int
)

declare @master table
(
    TableName varchar(10)
)

declare @TableName varchar(10)

insert ##a values (1), (2), (3)
insert ##b values (4), (5), (6)
insert ##c values (7), (8), (9)

insert @master values ('##a'), ('##b'),('##c')

declare looper cursor local static forward_only read_only for 
select TableName from @master
open looper
fetch next from looper into @TableName
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    insert @all exec('select Value from ' + @TableName)
    fetch next from looper into @TableName
end
close looper
deallocate looper

select * from @all

drop table ##a
drop table ##b
drop table ##c
```

If the tables are of different structures, please visit [Stored procedures and multiple result sets in T-SQL](http://sco.lt/7Visoz). It will squeeze the content of each table into a single XML cell. The article also explains how to read them back.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using many tables with different columns in your master table. You should loop your master table. Try like this,

```
   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = ''
DECLARE @start INT = 1
    ,@end INT = 0
    ,@tablename VARCHAR(100) = ''
DECLARE @TableList TABLE (
    id INT identity(1, 1)
    ,tablename VARCHAR(128)
    )

INSERT INTO @TableList (tablename)
SELECT DISTINCT table_name
FROM YourMasterTableName
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'productss'

SET @end = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE (@start <= @end)
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = (
            SELECT tablename
            FROM @TableList
            WHERE id = @start
            )
    SET @sql = (
            SELECT ',[' + column_name + ']'
            FROM YourMasterTableName M
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tablename
            FOR XML path('')
            )
    SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + stuff(@sql, 1, 1, '') + ' FROM ' + @tablename

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    SET @start = @start + 1
END
```